# Not able to understand How maven works with Spring MVC

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, maven, spring-mvc

I made a Hello word example in springMVC.Following are my steps.

1.Installed maven-eclipse integeration in eclipse.
2.Download maven and set environment variables,JAVA_HOME etc.
3.Check to see if maven is running via cmd and it is.
4.Create new maven project and in pom.xml,set spring core,web,web-mvc dependencies.
5.Create new Dynamic web project and under its properties->Deployment assembly I have added maven project.
6.Added spring jars core,mvc,web,context etc in dynamic web project lib folder.

It's all working now but I am not able to understand the working.

Before,I was trying to make it work without maven by copy and paste jars into lib,classpath,by makiing user library and adding jars to it and then add it to current project but every time it was giving some error.Sometimes it was classnotfound,sometimes it was context related.

Finally i tried this maven thing by searching some online tutorials and it works now.
But I am not able get it.Can anybody explain me in detail that how those spring jars getting picked during development and deployment.What exactly is maven doing that I was not doing before.I am in the state of total confusion.I know the flow of my mvc project(controllers,views etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven searches the libraries (they are also called artifacts in the Maven language) in repositories. In the Maven Central Repository many libraries are hosted - http://search.maven.org/. After Maven finds the libraries in a repository, it caches them in your local repository. It is in **${userDir}/.m2** The next time, Maven will look in your local repository, instead of downloading again from the Central Repository.

P.S You can specify many other repositories different than the Central Repository. This is done in the `<repositories>` tag in your `pom.xml`. The Central Repository is always searched by default.

Comment: thankyou for your ans but I want to do it without maven how can I achieve this.I was trying earlier but getting exception related to contextinitilazation or classnotfound

Comment: @ashu It's not enough information here to tell what was going wrong. Copy your project to another directory and roll-back your changes, so you don't use maven but specify libraries in Eclipse. Only after that, I think, the community can give you a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want use maven you have change your project setup. remove the pom.xml and copy all needed jar into the webapp/WEB-INF/libs folder.

Copy the jar from the a maven build(target folder). in this case you have all together without grabbing them one by one over then.